# Flowplayer won't stop() with jQuery function

Tags: jquery, flash, internet-explorer, flowplayer, bpopup

I am using the [VideoJS](http://videojs.com) HTML5 video player on a WordPress site I'm developing. The player launches in a modal window, and it works great for the most part, but the Flowplayer flash fallback for IE isn't behaving as I want.

When the user closes the modal box, playback should stop/pause. This works fine in HTML5, but not with Flowplayer. I've had a look at Flowplayer documentation but can't seem to get their suggested code to work. I've tried several variations, with no luck and cannot find a working example on the net.

It may be worth noting that VideoJS is called from WordPress, using VideoJS WP plugin.

The snippet below shows what I think it should work, where $f is the flow player selector, but I've tried other ways.

```
jQuery(function( $ ){
   $(document).ready(function(){

     $('.bClose').click(function(){
      $(".video-js")[0].player.pause();
        $f("video_1").stop();    /*  <-- THIS IS THE OFFENDING LINE OF CODE. */
        $('.video-js-box').bPopup().close();
      });

  });
});
```

I'm working from the HTML5 boilerplate, and this code is in my script-starter.js file.

Take a look at the [site under question](http://lchclearnetgraduates.com/newsite/annabel/)

I hope someone can help me get this to work.

Thanks in advance.

sPieLMaN

UPDATE: Am trying variations on this theme now...

```
        $('.bClose').click(function(){
        $(".video-js")[0].player.pause();
        $f($(".video-js-box").get(0)).pause();
        $('.video-js-box').bPopup().close();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is your modal plugin , find on Closed method in your modal documentation thenn u can do `$(video).remove();` or

```
var mPlayer = VideoJS.setup("my_video");
mPlayer.pause();
```